# How to Create a grid of desired Size by using react-data-grid in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

How to set the size of the final table created using react-data-grid.

For example if I want a 250*250 px size table, how to do that.

Is there any props already available for that?
or it needs to be done using the pure CSS.

---

### After solution provided by Saurav

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
this.dynamicHeight = 250px;
this.dyanmicWidth = 250px
<ReactDataGrid
minHeight={dynamicHeight}
minWidth={dynamicWidth}
...
/>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Saurav thanks for the reply , I did pass above two as a props to the component, and it worked however I am facing two issues right now.
1. there is an empty space at the right and bottom of the grid and
2. How to resize the text inside grid according to grid size

Comment: I have added the screenshot above